# can I get the shell to decide ls or less depending on filetype?

Tags: directory, less

Very often I find myself looking through directories using 'ls', then when I find the file I want, I use 'less' to look at the file.

```
So for example to find a mysql log file I might type
ls /var

then:
ls /var/log/

and then:
ls /var/log/mysql

and finally:
less /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
```

(its a bit of a contrived example, but hopefully you know what I am doing)

I find it annoying that I need to decide if the command should be ls or less.
Why can't 'less' determine if it has been given a directory and act as 'ls' ?

Is there a command that I can use instead of less that will act as ls or less depending on the file type ?  Or is there a common alias that people use ?

Comment: You're ***doing it wrong***...

Comment: @ewwhite Maybe you could be helpful and explain to him **why** it's wrong?

Comment: @ceejayoz I'm not sure I can. These are discrete commands. It's like trying to describe the color "blue".

Comment: @ewwhite I'll take a stab at it - "less works on files, not directory listings, and while you'd like it to work as ls on a directory, others would have different desires in that situation - it's better to just fail predictably. In most cases, you'll know in advance if something is a folder or a directory and get used to just using the right command in the first place."

Comment: @ceejayoz You got it. Much more tolerance her eon U&L versus ServerFault :)

Comment: What version of `less` are you using?  Recent versions (mine is 444) do exactly what you want automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Less *can* determine if it has been given a directory. Set the [`LESSOPEN`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=less&sektion=1#INPUT_PREPROCESSOR) environment variable to `~/bin/LESSPIPE` and make `~/bin/LESSPIPE` a script like the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -d "$1" ]; then
  exec /bin/ls -la "$1"
elif [ -f "$1" ]; then
  case "$1" in
    *.tar|ztar) exec tar tvvf "$1" 2>/dev/null;;
    *.tar.[dg]z|*.tar.z|*.tgz) exec gzip -dc "$1" | tar tvvf - 2>/dev/null;;
    *.tar.bz2) exec bzip2 -d <"$1" 2>/dev/null | exec tar tvvf - 2>/dev/null;;
    *.tar.Z|*.taz) exec uncompress -c "$1" | exec tar tvvf - 2>/dev/null;;
    *.zip) exec unzip -l "$1" 2>/dev/null;;
    *.lha) exec lha -v "$1" 2>/dev/null;;
    *.7z) exec 7z l "$1" 2>/dev/null;;
    *.[rs]pm) exec rpm -qilp "$1";;
    *.z|*.[dg]z) exec gzip -dc "$1" 2>/dev/null;;
    *.bz2) exec bzip2 -dc "$1";;
    *.xz) exec xz -dc "$1";;
    *.Z) exec uncompress -c "$1" 2>/dev/null;;
  esac
fi
```

You'll get a listing for directories and archives.

You can use [`lesskey`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=lesskey&sektion=1) instead of the environment variable to set the preprocessor. See the documentation for details.

Comment: I got this to work on ubuntu 12.04 by doing export LESSOPEN="|~/bin/LESSPIPE %s".  It does exactly what I want and a whole lot more useful stuff.

Answer (score 15):

In bash you could easily create a function to do this:

```
function less_ls()
{
  # True if file exists and is a regular file.
  if [ -f "${1}" ]
  then
    less "${1}"
  else
    ls "${1}"
  fi
}
```

Obviously you can rename the function into whatever you want by replacing the `less_ls` part, if you name it `less` it will have precedence of the executable `less`. If you want this to be defined automatically every time you start Bash you could copy paste it into your `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: Or the OP could use the right commands... +1 for the workaround.

Comment: Sure, he could, but he says he doesn't want to. It's not up to me to tell people what they have to prefer.